# Python Selenium : How to hover on an image and select the appeared buttons?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select a button that appears only when we hover on an image.

```
 def mouseHoverById(self, id):
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(id)
        self.mouseHover(element)


hover = "//li[@class='info-overlay']"
self.mouseHoverById(hover)
```

I get the following error

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//li[@class='info-overlay']"}

Comment: XPath query != id. You need either the ID, or the element. Can't hoverByXpath...

Comment: I have tried with CSS also:

def mouseHoverByCss(self, locator):
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(locator)
        self.mouseHover(element)
self.mouseHoverByCss("hover-border-wrapper display-buttons")

But, it didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have written your own function that takes in an ID and passes it into `.find_element_by_id(id)` but you've passed that function an XPath. The `.find_element_by_id()` method doesn't know what to do with the XPath that you've passed it because it's not an ID... thus the error.

My suggestion is to get rid of the function you wrote. There's very little point in writing a function like that when it's just 1-2 lines of code.

I don't know what `self.mouseHover(element)` is but I'm guessing it's another method that you've written to handle hovering an element. You'd can boil both of these functions down to two lines of code (no functions).

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='info-overlay']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

It's easy to read, easy to understand, and it's basic Selenium code that anyone that knows Selenium can recognize... and you don't have to debug it.

If you want to click a button that appears after the hover, then below the two lines above write some more code to click one of the buttons that appeared. You may need to add a wait after the hover to wait for the buttons to appear before you click on them.